# react map over input checkbox got unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render() {
  return (<div> this.list.map(obj => <input value={obj.name} type="checkbox" />)</div>)
}
```

Why above code doesn't work? got unexpected token.

Comment: You need to wrap code with curly brackets if you're going to use it inside of a React component.

Comment: @MichaelLyons what's wrong now? https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2813/

Comment: You had a bunch of spaces in your div bracket notation. Check this one: [https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2814/](https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2814/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to wrap the `map` part in `{}`, write it like this:

```
render() {
   return (
      <div> 
         {this.list.map(obj => <input key={obj.name} value={obj.name} type="checkbox" />)}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Assign unique `key` to each input element.

If list is a `state` variable then you need to write `this.state.list`, not sure about that so used the same code.

Comment: some formatting issue don't give unnecessary spaces, it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/kncwe7xu/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `map` into the curly brackets. The code should be as follows:

```
class HelloWidget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.list = [{
        "id": "exhibitions",
        "name": "Exhibitions"
      }, {
        "id": "festivals_n_concerts",
        "name": "Festivals & Concerts"
      }, {
        "id": "grand_opening",
        "name": "Grand Opening"
      }]
    }

    render() {
      return ( 
        <div> 
            {this.list.map(obj => <input key={obj.name} value={obj.name} type="checkbox" />)} 
        </div>
      )
    }


  }

React.render( <HelloWidget /> , document.getElementById('container'));
```

This will work. [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2815/).